# Lots of $_GET's in one script

Tags: php, variables, get

I want to pass about 20 variables to mysql table, using PHP scripts. Is there any better way than just doing:

```
$var1= preg_replace('/[^\w\.\-\& ]/', '', $_GET["var1"]);
$var2= preg_replace('/[^\w\.\-\& ]/', '',($_GET["var2"]));
$var3= preg_replace('/[^\w\.\-\& ]/', '',($_GET["var3"]));
```

etc.

And then having a massive line of code with:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_users (var1, var2, var3 etc.) VALUES('$var1', '$var2', '$var3' etc.)"
```

Thanks in advance,
Sondar

Comment: Aside from sql injection issues, what you have is pretty much the way to do it, unless you want to turn on `register_globals` (which is probably a very bad idea).

Comment: It is an array, so you can loop over it.

Comment: Do you happen to be familiar with a concept called "loop"?

Comment: To clarify, the variables aren't actually called var 1, var 2, var 3 etc. They're called stuffy like GAME_ID, USER_SCORE, USER_COMMENT (i.e.they're different data types and have very different names)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773406/insert-update-helper-function-using-pdo

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about the number of fields, 20 is not large.

However, you should use the database supplied escape function. If you're using mysql_* functions, you can use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

If you're using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) (recommended), use bound parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = $_GET;
foreach($i = 0;$i<count($a); $i++) {
    $b[] = preg_replace('/[^\w.-\& ]/', '', $a[$i]);
}
```

This should loop through all the post variables, validate them using your expression and dump it into $b. But I do not know any way to shorten `$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_users (var1, var2, var3 etc.) VALUES('$var1', '$var2', '$var3' etc.)"`

Comment: don't you mean for() instead of foreach?  actually you could just do `foreach($_GET as $var)` instead of your increment counting classic for() loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$get_values = array();
foreach($_GET as $name=>$val) {
    $get_values[$name] = preg_replace('/[^\w\.\-\& ]/', '', $val);
}

$query = 'INSERT INTO tbl_users ('.implode(', ', array_keys($get_values)).') VALUES('.implode(', ', $get_values).')';
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways. This one will assume that your `$_GET` variable names and the table field names match exactly.

```
$var_list = array('var1', 'var2', 'var3'); // as many as you want

// this filters GET to be just your variables
$params = array_intersect_key($_GET, array_fill_keys($var_list, ''));

$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_users (" . implode(',', array_keys($params)) . ") VALUES (";

foreach ($params as $val) {
    $query .= mysql_real_escape_string($val);
}
$query .= ")";
```

Edit:

As noted in comments, you need to be careful with the keys here. The general method of just sticking the keys into the query like this is very bad, *if* you don't filter them as I have done here. If instead of `array_keys($params)` it was something like `array_keys($_GET)` then you would be wide open for SQL injection. Make sure you're sanitizing the input, both keys and values.

Comment: from? everything that came from GET is being run through mysql_real_escape_string. the keys aren't, but he's specifying those himself. Please give an example of how to inject this. Note that just using GET keys it would be bad, yes - but my code is filtering them to only keys he allows.

Answer (score 0):

As outlined by everyone, the obvious way to simplify it is to use helper code. I have solved both problems with [for example](http://sourceforge.net/p/php7framework/wiki/db/):

```
foreach ($_GET->keys() as $id) {
    $var[$id] = $_GET->text[$id];
}
```

Where `$_GET->text["var12"]` automatically applies the regex filter.

Or for insertion without worrying about manual SQL escaping it's advisable to use prepared statements. But you still need special support for inserting rows:

```
db("INSERT INTO users (:?) VALUES (??)", array_keys($var),
                                         array_values($var));
```

Use a simple ORM to avoid manual SQL handicrafting. [Idiorm](http://j4mie.github.com/idiormandparis/) is nice.