# PHP PDO Update prepared statement problem

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

Hi everyone I've been trying my hand at PDO recently, and am currently trying to write a basic  database class for a project i'm working on. However i have ran into problems trying to write a function for carrying out an update query using prepared statements.

```
    function update($tabledata, $table, $where){

  $fields = array_keys($tabledata);
  $data = array_values($tabledata);
  $fieldcount = count($fields); 

  $wherefield = implode(array_keys($where));
  $whereval = implode(array_values($where));

  $this->query = "UPDATE $table SET ";
  $this->query .= '(' . implode($fields, ' = ?, ') . ' = ?)';
  $this->query .= " WHERE $wherefield = '$whereval'";

   $this->query = $this->_clean($this->query);
   $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($this->query) or die('Problem preparing query');
   $stmt->execute($data)or die('Problem executing query');

}
```

An example of it's use would be:

```
 $usertbl = 'users';
 $date = date("Y-m-d");
 $updatedata = array(
   'Username' => 'test',
   'Password' => 'unknown',
   'Email' => 'email',
   );
$where = array(
   'Username' => 'user'
    );

$Database->update($updatedata,$usertbl,$where);
```

This returns the following error:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute()
>   [pdostatement.execute]:
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '(Username = 'test', Password
>   = 'unknown', Email = 'email') WHERE Username = 'use' at line 1

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no parentheses in the `SET` clause of an `UPDATE` query.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Hence the syntax error when the `(` is hit. As long as you're trying to do things the right way with bound parameters, do it in the `WHERE` clause too!

Answer (score 1):

- your WHERE part doesn't utilize prepared statements
- using die() is NOT the way to go; do not use OR but check thrown exception instead.
- I am curious, what does _clean() method do?
- It seems your PDO in compatible mode. It would be better to turn it off
- I would like to see the final query, it usually helps a lot
- here is my question on the same topic, I hope you could find it useful:
  [Insert/update helper function using PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773406/insert-update-helper-function-using-pdo)
- however, I put PDO aside, and turned back to the old mysql which suits me better.