# Insert into table from array

Tags: php

```
$valor = $_POST['valor'];

$post_vars = array('iphone3g1', 'iphone3g2', 'nome', 'iphone41', 'postal', 'apelido');
foreach($post_vars as $var) {
    $$var = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]). "', ";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO clientes (iphone3g1, iphone3g2, nome, iphone41, postal, apelido, valor) VALUES ($$var '$valor')";
$query= mysql_query($sql);
```

Thank You so much for your previous answers guys.

I manares do write down this bit of code, i think it males scense but os not working.

I hope You can help me.

Thank You!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [php $_POST to get values - not the best way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135997/php-post-to-get-values-not-the-best-way)

Comment: hey you have to edit your earlier question or comment accepted answer, not starting new one. Just to make people not waste their time writing answers you've got already!

Comment: I edited the question, nobody answered. Can You help me please? Please, try to Explain the modifications You make to the code, i dont want just the code to paste but to learn. Thank You very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
$valor = $_POST['valor'];

$post_vars = array('iphone3g1', 'iphone3g2', 'nome', 'iphone41', 'postal', 'apelido');
$post_values = array();
foreach($post_vars as $var) {
    $post_values[$var] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]). "'";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO clientes (" . array_implode(',', array_keys($post_values)) . ") VALUES (" . array_implode(',', array_values($post_values)) . ")";
$query= mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: I am getting this error.                                           Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_implode() in /home/iphonepo/public_html/mywebsite.com/reparar.php on line 17

Answer (score 0):

```
$columns = array('iphone3g1', 'iphone3g2', 'nome', 'iphone41', 'postal', 'apelido', 'valor');
foreach($columns as $column)
  $values[$column] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$column]) . "'";
$rs = mysql_query("INSERT INTO clients (" . implode(',', $columns) . ") VALUES (" . implode(',', $values) . ")");
```