# Syntax error with PDO Prepared statements

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I've only just started working with prepared statements, and my first few examples worked out great, but now I'm running into an SQL syntax that I don't understand. I have a function that performs an INSERT, taking a parameter of an associative array, where the key of the array is the field and the value of the array is the value to be inserted. For example:

```
$arr = array("field1" => "value1",
             "field2" => "value2");

$this->insert("table", $arr);
```

Would perform:

```
INSERT INTO table ('field1', 'field2') VALUES ('value1', 'value2')
```

However, when trying to do it, I get the following error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''post_title', 'post_body') VALUES ('Testing!', '1 2 3!')' at
>   line 1

This is my function:

```
    /**
     * insert()
     * 
     * Performs an insert query
     * 
     * @param  string $table   The table to be inserted into
     * @param  array  $fields  An associative array of the fields to be inserted
     *                         and their respective values
     * @return void
     *
     */
    function insert($table, $fields) {
        if (empty($table) || empty($fields)) {
            trigger_error('insert(): one or more missing parameters', E_USER_ERROR);
        }

        if (!is_array($fields)) {
            trigger_error('insert(): second parameter expected to be array', E_USER_ERROR);
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($fields); $i++) {
            $mark[] = "?";
        }
    //(?, ?, ...)
    $mark = "(" . implode(", ", $mark) . ")";

    $bind = array_merge(array_keys($fields), array_values($fields));

    //INSERT INTO table (?, ?, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ...)
    $query = 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' '.$mark.' VALUES '.$mark;

    //Prepare and execute
    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
    var_dump($stmt);
    var_dump($bind);
    $stmt->execute($bind);
}
```

I'm calling it with:

```
$this->insert('post', array("post_title"=>"Testing!", "post_body"=>"1 2 3!"));
```

And the two var_dump()s at the end result in:

```
 object(PDOStatement)[7]
 public 'queryString' => string 'INSERT INTO post (?, ?) VALUES (?, ?)' (length=37)

array
  0 => string 'post_title' (length=10)
  1 => string 'post_body' (length=9)
  2 => string 'Testing!' (length=8)
  3 => string '1 2 3!' (length=6)
```

I may be wrong, but as I understand it, there is no way to check the actual query being sent to the server, so I honestly don't know where the SQL syntax is coming from. If anyone could point out what could be wrong, I would appreciate it tremendously.

Comment: Where is the tablename in your query?

Comment: You _cannot_ specify the field names like this. Explicit fieldnames aren't strings or integers, they are identifiers. If you are _really_ sure about column names, the first `$mark` could be `implode(',', array_keys($fields);`. I'd still whitelist those fieldnames...

Comment: Also: keep in mind PDO _emulates_ prepares / statements under certain conditions, unless told otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't bind identifiers. A thing unknown to all volunteer PDO evangelists.

You have to add identifiers using ol'good query building.

Have them whitelisted and make field names clause out of that list

See [Insert/update helper function using PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773406/insert-update-helper-function-using-pdo) for the complete implementation.

Comment: You're right, I just replaced the ? marks with the actual field names and it works now. I'll need to keep that in mind for now on!

Answer (score 0):

Field names should be surronded with ticks (``` `` ```) not quotes (`''`). It should be

```
INSERT INTO (`field1`, `field2`) VALUES ('value1', 'value2')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO ('field1', 'field2') VALUES ('value1', 'value2')
```

You forgot table name:

```
INSERT INTO table('field1', 'field2') VALUES ('value1', 'value2');
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, in the var_dump at the bottom you should see that I did include the table name.