# PHP Dynamic update function error?

Tags: php, mysql

I've made this dynamic update function, based on the fetch function, (same method, just another array for SET).

But it appears like there is an error with it.

```
    public function update($table, $columns = array(), array $criteria = null)
    {
        // The query base
        $query = "UPDATE $table";

        $query .= ' SET ' . implode(', ', array_map(function($column) {
            return "$column = ?";
        }, array_keys($columns)));

        // Start checking
        if ($criteria) {
            $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', array_map(function($column) {
                return "$column = ?";
            }, array_keys($criteria)));
        }

        $update = $this->pdo->prepare($query) or die('An error has occurred with the following message:' . $query);
        $update->execute(array_values($criteria));
    }
```

And that is the error I am getting (Line 179 = `$update->execute(array_values($columns, $criteria));):

What is wrong with it? why am I getting that error?

EDIT NEW ERROR:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in C:\xampp\htdocs\argonite\includes\class\MYSQL\Database.class.php:179 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\argonite\includes\class\MYSQL\Database.class.php(179): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\argonite\index.php(8): Database->update('argonite_server...', Array, Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\argonite\includes\class\MYSQL\Database.class.php on line 179
```

Comment: array_values() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given

Comment: php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Comment: this function is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: @YourCommonSense Only if the column names are user-provided.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading the d*%# error message

Answer (score 2):

this approach with helper functions is wrong.

what you really need is a generic query() function that supports a few extended placeholder types. Or, at least, [a function to create SET statement out of array and a list of allowed fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3921798/285587).

this way you will have something like this:

```
$allowed = array("name","surname","email","password"); // allowed fields

$sql = "UPDATE users SET ".pdoSet($allowed,$values)." WHERE id = :id";
$stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$values['id'] = $_POST['id'];
$stm->execute($values);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong syntax here:

```
array_values($columns, $criteria)
```

As the array_values() function is called by 1 parameter and you are passing two. So remove any one and pass the array in this function.

For more read here: [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

Comment: Without $columns I will only get missing parameters SQL error, why?

Comment: @JunatanmDegraded because of array_values make the index of value 0,1,2 and its need the parameters so I think you should not use this function.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$update->execute(array_merge(array_values($columns), array_values($criteria)));
```

`array_merge` will concatenate the values from `$columns` and `$criteria`.

Comment: Does it still say "No parameters were bound"?

Comment: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens